# Adding syntax highlighting to markdown saved in DB in SvelteKit

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, sveltekit

I am trying to make a markdown blog where I have an in browser markdown editor. I can display the markdown by using a lexer like marked. The problem I am encountering is when I am trying to add syntax highlighting for code blocks. I created a custom markdown parser with marked, but for some reasons, getHighlighter was looking into my api routes instead of node modules.

I also tried using highlight.js and various other highlighters like prism and lexers like mark-it. Most of them just didn't do any syntax highlighting. I am not sure if this a sveltekit problem or a highlighter problem

```
// utils.ts
import {Marked} from 'marked'
import {getHighlighter} from 'shiki'

export const marked = new Marked(
    markedHighlight({
        async: true,
        async highlight(code, lang) {
            const highlighter = await getHighlighter({
                theme: 'nord'
            });
            const html = highlighter.codeToHtml(code, { lang });
            return html;
        }
    })
);

//+page.ts

async function load({params}){
  ...
  return await marked.parse(txt)
}
```

```
SvelteKitError: Not found: /themes/nord.json
    at resolve (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:495:13)
    at resolve (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:295:5)
    at #options.hooks.handle (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\index.js:63:56)
    at Module.respond (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:292:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  status: 404,
  text: 'Not Found'
}
SvelteKitError: Not found: /dist/onig.wasm
    at resolve (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:495:13)
    at resolve (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:295:5)
    at #options.hooks.handle (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\index.js:63:56)
    at Module.respond (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:292:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  status: 404,
  text: 'Not Found'
}
SvelteKitError: Not found: /themes/nord.json
    at resolve (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:495:13)
    at resolve (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runruntime\server\respond.js:295:5)
    at #options.hooks.handle (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\index.js:63:56)
    at Module.respond (C:\Users\leung\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\mdsvex\markdown-blog-mdsvex-ts\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:292:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  status: 404,
  text: 'Not Found'
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's probably not getting those json fils in themes into the build.  Do you have anything in your `svelte.config.js` to nudge this?  In particular you might want to take a look at https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options#optimizedeps-include

Comment: @possum I can't really find a way to include the necessary files inside of the pre bundle. the include in vite seems to ignore node modules entirely so I am not sure...

Comment: I've not played with shiki before and it seems to be a smaller package.  Have you considered trying something else like hljs or prisma just to see if you get anything better?  There are definitely some explicit tutorials on using hljs and marked

Comment: @possum I have. They just straight up do nothing though.